# Why Am getting the request-body content as empty?

Tags: node.js, node-modules

when i submit the register form ,the data from that register page should be posted on the console.. and I try to print that result using "req.body.Username" , it says undefined and when i view the req in console. The body seems to be an empty set like " {} ", how to post my form details in body to view in console and how to get rid of that "undefined" error?

**app.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const flash = require('connect-flash');
const path = require('path');
const request = require('request')
const expressValidator = require('express-validator');
const authRoutes = require('./routes/auth-routes');
const session = require('express-session');
const passport = require('passport');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mysql = require('mysql');
const db = require('./config/db');
const registerc = require('./registerc');
const loginc = require('./loginc');
const registerRoute = require('./routes/register');
const fs = require('fs');

// const request = require('./modules/module1')
const app = express();

// set view engine
app.set('view engine', 'pug');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
// set up routes
app.use('/auth', authRoutes);
app.use('', registerRoute);

// create home route
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
            res.render('home');
            res.render('mycourses', {
                final1: final1
            });
            res.render('recent', {
                final2: final2
            });
        });


// fetching course details

request(options, function (error, response, result) {
    if (error) throw new Error(error);
    // console.log(result);
    // final1 = JSON.stringify(result)
    final1 = JSON.parse(result);
    // console.log(final1);
});

// fetching User recent Activity

request(options, function (error, response, result) {
    if (error) throw new Error(error);
    // console.log(result);
    final2 = JSON.parse(result);
    // console.log(final2);
    //   console.log(final2.length)
});

app.use(session(
    {
        secret : 'secret',
        saveUninitialised : true,
        resave : true
    }
));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());


app.use(expressValidator({
    errorFormatter: function(param, msg, value) {
        var namespace = param.split('.')
        , root    = namespace.shift()
        , formParam = root;

      while(namespace.length) {
        formParam += '[' + namespace.shift() + ']';
      }
      return {
        param : formParam,
        msg   : msg,
        value : value
      };
    }
}));

app.use(flash());    

// app.use(function(res,req,next){
//  res.locals.success_msg = req.flash('success_msg');
//  res.locals.error_msg = req.flash('error_msg');
//  res.locals.error = req.flash('error');
//  next();
// })

// app.post('/api/register',registerc.register);
// app.post('/api/login', loginc.login);



app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('app now listening for requests on port 3000');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `app.js`, update the register auth from

```
app.use('', registerRoute);
```

To

```
app.use('/soemRoute', registerRoute);
```